# Create column with unique identifier when adjacent fields are identical

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, combinations, partitioning

The below is an example of an existing table (except for the activity instance column). I'd like the activity_instance column to create/add a numeric identifier each time a unique combination presents itself in the three adjacent columns for each individual (unique_id), i.e. when unique_id, activity and date match, it's assigned the instance of 1 for that person, and so on. This same combination could appear more than once later in the dataset.

The idea is to distinguish which events belong together and which not. This instance identifier should be unique, also among different cases and activities.

| unique_id | activity | date | activity_instance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | activity_a | 2016-04-01 | 1 |
| 1234 | activity_a | 2016-04-01 | 1 |
| 1234 | activity_b | 2016-04-01 | 2 |
| 5678 | activity_a | 2019-09-01 | 1 |
| 5678 | activity_a | 2019-09-01 | 1 |
| 65431 | activity_c | 2019-09-01 | 1 |
| 1234 | activity_a | 2019-09-01 | 3 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `dense_rank` :

```
select *
  , dense_rank() over (partition by unique_id order by date,activity) as activity_instance
from tablename
```